# How to detect if html audio tag can't play audio file

Tags: html, html5-audio

Some audio/ogg files with special codec can't be played with html5 audio tag. How can I detect it to show a message for user to download file and play with special player?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the audio element's [`canplaytype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#Methods) method to detect whether or not the current browser can play a specific codec.

Example from [diveintohtml5](http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html)

```
function canPlay (codec) {
    var a = document.createElement('audio');
    return !!(a.canPlayType && a.canPlayType(codec).replace(/no/, ''));
}

canPlay('audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"'); // true or false
```